# Value is getting repeated

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL looks like this:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(technologies.tech) AS technologies, personal.city, GROUP_CONCAT(languages.language) AS languages 
FROM personal 
INNER JOIN technologies ON technologies.uid = personal.uid 
INNER JOIN languages ON languages.uid = personal.uid 
WHERE personal.uid = 88
```

**The result:**

```
| technologies        |  city          |  languages               |
|---------------------|:--------------:|-------------------------:|
| PHP,HTML,JavaScript |  Chicago       |  English,English,English |
```

As you see `English` is getting repeated. How can I make it to appear only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregation query with unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` and no `GROUP BY`.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCTt.tech) AS technologies, p.city, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.language) AS languages 
FROM personal p INNER JOIN
     technologies t
     ON t.uid = p.uid INNER JOIN
     languages l
     ON l.uid = p.uid 
WHERE p.uid = 88
GROUP BY p.city;
```

Notes:

- `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT)` answers your question
- Table aliases make the query much easier to read.
- `p.city` is bare in the `SELECT`.  Recent versions of MySQL will complain; so I added the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!